# Google Protocol Buffers Visual Studio build customization (C++, generic)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, customization, protocol-buffers

I'm looking for a nice Visual Studio (2015) build customization (.props/.targets) for the Google Protocol Buffer Compiler (protoc.exe).

I've adapted my own version from a QtMOC build customization but it's not very nice, still has some errors and isn't working on all our development machines.

**.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="ProtocolBuffer">
      <Targets>_ProtocolBuffer</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>
  <UsingTask TaskName="ProtocolBuffer" TaskFactory="XamlTaskFactory" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0">
    <Task>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml</Task>
  </UsingTask>
  <Target
    Name="_ProtocolBuffer"
    BeforeTargets="$(ProtocolBufferBeforeTargets)"
    AfterTargets="$(ProtocolBufferAfterTargets)"
    Condition="'@(ProtocolBuffer)' != ''"
    DependsOnTargets="$(ProtocolBufferDependsOn);ComputeProtocolBufferOutput"
    Outputs="@(ProtocolBuffer.OutputFile)"
    Inputs="@(ProtocolBuffer);%(ProtocolBuffer.AdditionalDependencies);$(MSBuildProjectFile)">
    <ItemGroup Condition="'@(SelectedFiles)' != ''">
      <ProtocolBuffer Remove="@(ProtocolBuffer)" Condition="'%(Identity)' != '@(SelectedFiles)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="%(ProtocolBuffer.ExecutionDescription)" />
    <ProtocolBuffer
      Condition="'@(ProtocolBuffer)' != '' and '%(ProtocolBuffer.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true'"
      CommandLineTemplate="%(ProtocolBuffer.CommandLineTemplate)"
      OutputFile="@(ProtocolBuffer.OutputFile)"
      AdditionalOptions="%(ProtocolBuffer.AdditionalOptions)"
      Inputs="@(ProtocolBuffer)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ComputeProtocolBufferOutput" Condition="'@(ProtocolBuffer)' != ''">
    <MakeDir Directories="%(ProtocolBuffer.OutputDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**.props**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup
    Condition="'$(ProtocolBufferBeforeTargets)' == '' and '$(ProtocolBufferAfterTargets)' == ''">
    <ProtocolBufferBeforeTargets>Midl</ProtocolBufferBeforeTargets>
    <ProtocolBufferAfterTargets>CustomBuild</ProtocolBufferAfterTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProtocolBufferDependsOn>
    _SelectedFiles;$(ProtocolBufferDependsOn)
    </ProtocolBufferDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ProtocolBuffer>
      <OutputDir>%(RootDir)%(Directory)</OutputDir>
      <OutputFile>$(OutputDir)%(Filename).pb.h</OutputFile>
      <CommandLineTemplate>$(VIZEXTERN_PROTOCOLBUFFERS_BINDIR)\protoc.exe --proto_path=%(OutputDir) --cpp_out=%(OutputDir) %(FullPath)</CommandLineTemplate>
      <Outputs>%(OutputFile)</Outputs>
      <ExecutionDescription>Compiling protobuffer %(Filename).h</ExecutionDescription>
      <AdditionalDependencies>%(FullPath)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </ProtocolBuffer>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

**.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectSchemaDefinitions xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Build.Framework.XamlTypes;assembly=Microsoft.Build.Framework" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:transformCallback="Microsoft.Cpp.Dev10.ConvertPropertyCallback">
  <Rule Name="ProtocolBuffer" PageTemplate="tool" DisplayName="Protocol Buffer" Order="200">
    <Rule.DataSource>
      <DataSource Persistence="ProjectFile" ItemType="ProtocolBuffer" />
    </Rule.DataSource>
    <Rule.Categories>
      <Category Name="General">
        <Category.DisplayName>
          <sys:String>General</sys:String>
        </Category.DisplayName>
      </Category>
      <Category Name="Command Line" Subtype="CommandLine">
        <Category.DisplayName>
          <sys:String>Command Line</sys:String>
        </Category.DisplayName>
      </Category>
    </Rule.Categories>
    <StringListProperty Name="Inputs" Category="Command Line" IsRequired="true" Switch=" ">
      <StringListProperty.DataSource>
        <DataSource Persistence="ProjectFile" ItemType="ProtocolBuffer" SourceType="Item" />
      </StringListProperty.DataSource>
    </StringListProperty>
    <StringProperty Name="OutputFile" HelpContext="0" DisplayName="Output File Name" Switch="&quot;[value]&quot;" />
    <StringProperty Name="OutputDir" HelpContext="0" DisplayName="Output Directory" Switch="&quot;[value]&quot;" />
    <StringProperty Name="CommandLineTemplate" DisplayName="Command Line" Visible="False" IncludeInCommandLine="False" />
    <DynamicEnumProperty Name="ProtocolBufferBeforeTargets" Category="General" EnumProvider="Targets" IncludeInCommandLine="False">
      <DynamicEnumProperty.DisplayName>
        <sys:String>Execute Before</sys:String>
      </DynamicEnumProperty.DisplayName>
      <DynamicEnumProperty.Description>
        <sys:String>Specifies the targets for the build customization to run before.</sys:String>
      </DynamicEnumProperty.Description>
      <DynamicEnumProperty.ProviderSettings>
        <NameValuePair Name="Exclude" Value="^ProtocolBufferBeforeTargets|^Compute" />
      </DynamicEnumProperty.ProviderSettings>
      <DynamicEnumProperty.DataSource>
        <DataSource Persistence="ProjectFile" HasConfigurationCondition="true" />
      </DynamicEnumProperty.DataSource>
    </DynamicEnumProperty>
    <DynamicEnumProperty Name="ProtocolBufferAfterTargets" Category="General" EnumProvider="Targets" IncludeInCommandLine="False">
      <DynamicEnumProperty.DisplayName>
        <sys:String>Execute After</sys:String>
      </DynamicEnumProperty.DisplayName>
      <DynamicEnumProperty.Description>
        <sys:String>Specifies the targets for the build customization to run after.</sys:String>
      </DynamicEnumProperty.Description>
      <DynamicEnumProperty.ProviderSettings>
        <NameValuePair Name="Exclude" Value="^ProtocolBufferAfterTargets|^Compute" />
      </DynamicEnumProperty.ProviderSettings>
      <DynamicEnumProperty.DataSource>
        <DataSource Persistence="ProjectFile" ItemType="" HasConfigurationCondition="true" />
      </DynamicEnumProperty.DataSource>
    </DynamicEnumProperty>
    <StringListProperty Name="Outputs" DisplayName="Outputs" Visible="False" IncludeInCommandLine="False" />
    <StringProperty Name="ExecutionDescription" DisplayName="Execution Description" Visible="False" IncludeInCommandLine="False" />
    <StringListProperty Name="AdditionalDependencies" DisplayName="Additional Dependencies" IncludeInCommandLine="False" Visible="false" />
    <StringProperty Name="AdditionalOptions" Subtype="AdditionalOptions" Category="Command Line">
    <StringProperty.DisplayName>
        <sys:String>Additional Options</sys:String>
      </StringProperty.DisplayName>
      <StringProperty.Description>
        <sys:String>Additional Options</sys:String>
      </StringProperty.Description>
    </StringProperty>
  </Rule>
  <ItemType Name="ProtocolBuffer" DisplayName="Protocol Buffer" />
  <FileExtension Name="*.proto" ContentType="ProtocolBuffer" />
  <ContentType Name="ProtocolBuffer" DisplayName="Protocol Buffer" ItemType="ProtocolBuffer" />
</ProjectSchemaDefinitions>
```